# Rails, trouble with scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I want to create scope for a model I have, but I want it to evaluated a count on a related model... like say:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
  scope :with_images, self.photo.count > 0
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :thing
end
```

I should then have a scope which would work like

```
Thing.where('some conditions').with_images
```

I get a `NoMethodError` on photos, why wouldn't this be available as a relation? I don't want to use it as a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things going on here. First, you're trying to call photo, instead of photos.

However, the you're still going to get an error because at the time of execution, `self` refers to the constant Thing, and not an instance of Thing. The declaration `has_many :photos` defines a method `photos` for instances of Thing. Therefore, Thing (the constant) doesn't have a method called photos.

tl;dr Just use a `:joins` argument since it will only find records that have photos

```
scope :with_images, :joins => :photos
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
self.photos.count > 0
```

or if you're using counter cache:

```
self.photos_count > 0
```